# Program crashes sometimes when dynamically allocating memory

Tags: c++

I am learning about pointers and dynamically allocating memory.  So my question I guess is more of a technical issue.  Whenever it seems I use the 'new' keyword to allocate memory for whatever I am doing, my program will sometimes crash.  Sometimes not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>  //I added this header file to get the NULL, this is not originally from the book

using namespace std;

int main(){
   double *salesArry = NULL;
   double total = 0.0, average;
   int numDays, count;

   cout << "How many days of sales figured do you wish to process ";
   cin >> numDays;

   salesArry = new double[numDays];

   cout << "Enter the sales figures below.\n";
   for(count = 0; count < numDays; count++){
       cout << "Day " << (count + 1) << ": ";
       cin >> salesArry[count];          
   }

   for(count = 0; count < numDays; count++){
       total += salesArry[count];
   }

   average = total/numDays;

   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
   cout << "\n\nTotal Sales: $" << total << endl;
   cout << "\n\nAverage Sales: $" << average << endl;

   delete [] salesArry;
   salesArry = NULL;

   return 0;
}
```

Full disclaimer: I am a student, this is NOT homework. I posted a book example.  I copied it word for word and still my program crashes.  My only reason for posting code is someone will proably ask "Can we see the code".  Now the project I was working on is doing the same thing (crashes) so I doubt that both the book and I are wrong so that is why I'm guessing its a technical issue.  The IDE I am using is Dev C++ and its the default compiler.

This is from Tony Gaddis's book "Starting Out with C++" Chapter 9, page 524

Comment: The syntax is `[]` not `()` for allocating an array `salesArry = new double[numDays]`

Comment: Its fine if you guys give me thumbs down, just note this is from the book

Comment: Are you sure? If it is, fair enough, you found an error in the book. But are you sure it's not just you copied it wrong?

Comment: @dragonore For what it's worth [we have no problem helping with homework questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) provided they are good questions.

Comment: I swear the book uses [] and not ()

Comment: I can't find this code on page 524. Which edition?

Comment: Its on page 524 and continues onto page 525.  Chapter 9 Pointers

Comment: Eighth edition  Orange on cover

Comment: @dragonore: Page 524? Figure 9-14? I have 8th edition in front of me and it says `[]` not `()`. I concede that their choice of font makes it a little hard to tell the difference.

Comment: line 23 from program 9-14 is `sales = new double[numDays];` in the 8th edition of the book.  This is the correct syntax.

Comment: Um now you've changed it in the question. WTF.

Comment: Yes in my earlier comment I said "I swear the book uses [] and not ().  So originally I had () instead of [].  However I still get crashes, so I might just reinstall dev c++ and see if that fixes it, but thanks for everything

Comment: Reinstalling Dev-C++ won't do anything. :P It's more likely you didn't recompile properly after fixing the `()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new double(numDays);
```

Whoops! When you transcribed the book, you made a typographical error. (I can confirm that the 8th Edition, which you said you're using, does not make this mistake (figure 9-14, *et al.*).

To dynamically allocate an array, you must use square brackets, otherwise you're just initialising one dynamically-allocated `double` with the value `numDays`.

```
new double[numDays];
```

Comment: It still crashes sometimes, would you suspect a compiler issue or what would be your assesment.  Obviously the book and I can't both be wrong, so that is why I would think logically it must be a technical issue.

Comment: @dragonore: _"Obviously the book and I can't both be wrong"_ I don't see how that's in any way "obvious". Without being able to reproduce the problem I cannot make an assessment. But if you _really_ changed `()` to `[]` and it still crashes then I have no idea why because the code is fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
salesArry = new double(numDays);
```

That line doesn't create an array of `numDays` `double`s, it allocates a single `double` and initializes it to `numDays`.

To create an array, you would use:

```
salesArry = new double[numDays];
```

In C++, however, it is preferable to use `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocating arrays by hand:

```
std::vector<double> salesArray (numDays);
```

Comment: Oh I agree, if it was me, and I was to program this, I would use a vector too.  I however was just posting the book example, but yes your right on your approach.